# Adding new rows based on column value in SQL?

Tags: sql, vertica

```
Comment         weekid  acc1    acc2    acc3    acc4       value
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Current data        1   a      b       c       d             2
Current data        1   a      b       c       e             3
Line to be added    1   a      b       c       Fixed New     value of d/value of e
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: What's your dbms and your expect result, sample data?that really help

Comment: we are using vertica expected result is i need to add that last line where its says line to be added in comment field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you just want `union all`:

```
select weekid, acc1, acc2, acc3, acc4, value
from t
union all
select weekid, acc1, acc2, acc3, 'Fixed new' as acc4,
       ( max(case when acc4 = 'd' then value end) /
         max(case when acc4 = 'e' then value end)
       ) as value
from t
group by weekid, acc1, acc2, acc3;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for response however this will always result value column being Null

Comment: @KaranKochhar . . . I don't see how that would be the case.